# Parameterised Routes in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5, angular-routing

Based on [LINK](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/parameterised-routes/) from here -
in my application I've routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'blog/:id', component: BlogComponent },
 { path: 'blog/moo', component: MooComponent },
];
```

And there is information that:

> If we visited /blog/moo we would show MooComponent even though it
>   matches the path for the first blog/:id route as well.
>
> Important Non-parameterised routes take precedence over parameterised
>   routes.

Unfortunately it doesn't work like that. If I will go to url `blog/moo` then routing will treat `moo` as `Id` and will open `BlogComponent`.

I wondering how can I solve I have 2 ideas:

1. I can change path. **blog**/id and **blogs**/moo.
2. I can use [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) but it could be slightly problematic when I'll change previos url segments. So this function should be very well prepared.

What do you think? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

According to `Angular official documentation` [refer to this](https://angular.io/guide/router#example-config)

### The router selects the route with a first match wins strategy.

- > The router selects the route with a first match wins strategy.
  >   Wildcard routes are the least specific routes in the route
  >   configuration. Be sure it is the last route in the configuration.
- > The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by
  >   design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching
  >   routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific
  >   routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are
  >   listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the
  >   default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every 
  >   URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

[Even this explains the same regarding the route prioritization](https://angular.io/guide/router#!#wildcard-route)

So you should keep your routes in reverse order:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'blog/moo', component: MooComponent },
 { path: 'blog/:id', component: BlogComponent },
];
```

I want to highlight a point from above statements:

**Note:**

**More specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.**

Since **'blog/moo'** is more specific, you need to place it above **'blog/:id'**

[**I have created a PLUNKER for your example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/lxruEafdaadjimyi3InY?p=preview)

Comment: But it doesn't work if I've got nested routes: `{ path: 'blog/moo', component: MooComponent, children: {path: "", loadChildren: "..."}}`

Comment: children means? can you edit my plunker and add those?

Comment: Ok I've found problem in children routing I had:
  `{ path: "**", component: Page404Component }` so your solution is still properly.

Answer (score 2):

in

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'blog/:id', component: BlogComponent },
 { path: 'blog/moo', component: MooComponent },
];
```

try writing it as :

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'blog/moo', component: MooComponent },
 { path: 'blog/:id', component: BlogComponent },

];
```

It should work now.In angular there is significance in the order you write the routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the order of routes definition. The first matching route always wins.
It is not really possible that navigating to `/blog/moo` will trigger both components.

But you can reference BlogComponent inside the MooComponent

Comment: I'd like to avoid such solution since If there (in moo) will be nested (lazy loaded) routes than it might not work.